# falla bucle al leer un fichero con direcciones ip python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

hola tengo un código en python el cual envía múltiples comandos guardados en un fichero txt **comandos.txt** a un core en la empresa donde trabajo, sucede que hay otro fichero denominado **listaip.txt** el cual contiene la cantidades de direcciones ip que debería recorrer el bucle, lo irónico es que si solicito los datos del usuario dentro del ciclo se repite dependiendo de la cantidad de lineas o direcciones ip escritas en el código, es decir, si tenemos tres (3) direcciones ip en el fichero el bucle son tres veces.

el motivo de esta solicitud es de como enviar los comandos en **comandos.txt** a las **n** cantidades de direcciones ip del fichero **listaip.txt**

PD: será problemas de conexión?, de la librería? que podría estar haciendo mal? y la versión de python es 2.7.15

```
import sys
import os
import platform
import socket
import paramiko


    try:
    #solicitamos los datos al usuario
    usuario = raw_input("ingrese su usuario de acceso: ")
    clave = raw_input("ingrese su contrasena: ")

    #leemos el archivo listaip.txt y comandos.txt
    #en comandos.txt escribimos los comandos a enviar a los equipos remotos
    archivo1 = open("listaip.txt","r")
    archivo2 = open("comandos.txt","r")
    archivo3 = open("objetivo.txt","w")
    #guardamos en un archivo los resultados obtenidos al final del recorrido
    #leemos lo que contiene los archivos e igualamos a las variables del bucle
    terminales = archivo1.readlines()
    comandoss = archivo2.readlines()
    #bucle que recorre de acuerdo a las n cantidas de direcciones ip activas
    for host in terminales:
        #rstrip eliminamos los espacios que pudieren quedar antes o despues del salto de linea
        host = host.rstrip()
        for command in comandoss:
            #bucle que funciona de acuerdo a la cantidad de direcciones ip almacenadas en el archivo listaip.txt
            command = command.rstrip()
            name = socket.getfqdn()
            #eliminamos los espacios vacios
            #inicializamos el cliente ssh
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            #leemos la clave local
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            #efectuamos la conexion
            ssh.connect(host, username=usuario, password=clave)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
            #leemos la salida
            salida = stdout.read()
            #creamos una lista vacia
            lista =[]
            #añadimos los elementos de la salida al final de la lista
            lista.append(salida)
            #escribimos en el archivo
            archivo3.write(str((name + ":" + salida +"\n")))
            ssh.close()
            #cerramos la conexion y todos los archivos
    archivo1.close()
    archivo2.close()
    archivo3.close()
except:
    print("error al ejecutar operacion")
    return
```

sepase que los resultados el los guarda con normalidad en un fichero de nombre **objetivo.txt** y la idea es que valga la redundancia ejecute el bucle y guarde todo en **objetivo.txt**

listaip.txt

```
10.1.0.1 
10.1.0.3
10.1.0.6
```

comandos.txt

```
show clock 
!
show vlan
```

en esta parte no existe problema alguno

Comment: No es claro el problema. Cuando dices "lo irónico es que si solicito los datos del usuario *dentro del ciclo* se repite dependiendo de la cantidad de lineas o direcciones ip escritas en el código", si la solicitud de datos está dentro del ciclo yo esperar;ia que se repita N veces.

Comment: En principio noto que tu bloque try: debería ir sin sangría. Eso podría estar haciendo que no recibas correctamente un mensaje de un error.
Por otro lado, veo que estás abriendo y cerrando la conexión ssh por cada comando, cuando podrías hacerlo (convendría) una vez por terminal al que te conectas.
Quizás acomodando eso se pueda visualizar mejor el error para corregirlo.
Saludos!

Comment: Dentro del *except* veo una sentencia *return*. ¿No será que ese código se encuentra dentro de una función y estás usando recursividad?